# Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch

I am making the following HTTP request from my frontend.  All of my `GET` requests made in the same way work, but the following `UPDATE` fails:

> Access to fetch at
>   '127.0.0.1/backend/path'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Method UPDATE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in
>   preflight response.

### Frontend Request

```
return fetch(
      `127.0.0.1/backend/path`,
      {
        method: "UPDATE",
        body: JSON.stringify(newClass),
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, UPDATE",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + getState().authToken
        }
      }
    )
```

### Backend Flask endpoint

```
@app.route('/backend/path', methods=['UPDATE'])
@authenticate
def update_data():
    return {"data": "has been updated"}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374247/always-got-method-delete-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-methods-in-prefl) suggests adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header, but this is already present on my request!  I also don't just want to turn off CORS for my browser, as I need it implemented correctly.

Comment: The backend has to send CORS headers lol. I’ve also never heard of an UPDATE http method.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` must be in the `OPTIONS` **response** header. Adding it to the request header doesn't affect the backend's permissions.

Comment: Those headers are **response** headers, not request headers. See the many, many, questions about CORS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Always got Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374247/always-got-method-delete-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-methods-in-prefl) Read the answer again, closely. The answer is discussing adding the header to the server-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods` must be in the `OPTIONS` **response** header. Remember that the backend controls how it is accessed. You cannot add allowed methods simply by requesting them.

Also, `UPDATE` isn't a standard HTTP verb. Do you mean `PUT` or `PATCH`?

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my CORS confusion. `flask-cors` already adds these headers to the responses, so I just needed to delete them from my requests. And I definitely meant `PUT`, not sure where `UPDATE` came from. In fact, just switching UPDATE->PUT fixed the error entirely. Thanks again!